# Add localizable language to Xcode from shell script

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I'm trying to add a new localized strings to the project, from shell script.
Is there any way to add them,
like when you press the + button under the localizations in the project Info?

I tried to copy the files to the project folder before the build.
But Xcode didn't detect them.


Thanks!